# Run a python script in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

In fact my question is simple. I tried the most straightfoward (print("Hello world!")) script in Python 2.7.13  but it doesn't work. I work with Sublime Text 3. Here is a snapshot with the error message :

[image]

And the Python.sublime-build file :

[image]

Comment: One of your problems is that you selected the `Syntax Check` variant of the python build (that's what the `-m py_compile` is doing).

Comment: Thanks OdatNurd, so what should I do instead?

Comment: Moreover, I also noticed that C:\Python27 wasn't in the path. Is it a problem?

Comment: If you're using the built in python build system, choose the other variant. If you're making your own (looks like you have a python build open in the other tab), replace "-m py_compile" with "-u" in your command line to make python run the program instead of compiling it.

Comment: The directory that the python binary is in not being in the path should also be a problem, since the build system doesn't seem to be using an explicit path on the python command to tell it where python is. However that's usually signaled by an explicit error message. I'd fix it just to be safe.

Comment: So, I tried to make my own python build system because it didn't work. The Python.sublime-build file had just been added to my question, if you want to see it and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: @wim identified your problem below. Note however that the build your image is showing and the build that is generating the output in the build window are different. Assuming that represents a result from after you fixed the problem mentioned in the answer below, your other issue is that it's still using the built in python build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublimetext highlights in pink if there are problems in the build system JSON.

In your case, you'll need to use forward slashes or escape the backslashes (`\\`) for the path to the interpreter.

*Note*: if you're not doing anything custom in the build system, you may as well just select the default Python build system.

Comment: @win : How to use the default Python build system? I'm a total beginner..

Comment: @AnthonyHauser **`Tools → Build System → Python`**. It's really not that hard. Sublime will not hold your hand the whole way. You need to explore the menus and find out what each thing does. You need to write config files by hand. You need to *carefully* read error and other output messages. Use Google. Read [the docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html). Take initiative. It's a *programmer's* editor, not Windows Notepad.

Comment: By the way, if you're just learning Python, start with Python 3, not the outdated and deprecated version 2. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches in the long run. And whatever you do, don't use Learn Python the Hard Way. It sucks.